# Android using AutoCompleteTextView with Location suggestions (Using Geocoder and getFromLocationName())

Tags: android, geolocation, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I have an AutoCompleteTextView where i want to search for locations, example:
You type "vig" and the AutoCompleteTextView list shows the 5 best results for that:
"4560 Vig", "Juan Pablo Perez..", "The Vig 4041...", "Vig"
Another example, you type "vigo": it says the right place: "Vigo, Pontevedra" and you can select it and put it on the AutoCompleteTextView.

For now, what i have is working almost good but i have one error:

1. The display list is only showing when you delete on character, if not doesn't show, and what it shows is the last string result, example:
   you have typed "vigo", and nothing appears, you delete the "o" and the display list shows results for "vigo" instead of "vig", that is what is typed in the AutoCompleteTextView in the moment.

---

I perform the search for the locations in an AsyncTask:

```
private class SearchAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

     @Override
     protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
         //adapter.clear();
         String[] addressArray = getStreetList(query);
             return addressArray;
     }    
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String[] addressArray) {
         if(addressArray == null)
             Toast.makeText(NewRouteActivity.this, "No address obtained from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         else{
            adapter.clear();
            for(String address: addressArray){
                adapter.add(address); <------HERE IS THE 2ND ERROR
                Log.d("ASYNC", address);
             }
         }
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {}
     @Override
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Here is my AutoCompleteTextView Code:

```
String[] array = {};    
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array);//simple_dropdown_item_1line
autoFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
autoTo.setAdapter(adapter);
asyncSearch = new SearchAddress();
autoFrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (((AutoCompleteTextView) autoFrom).isPerformingCompletion()) {return;}
        if (s.length() < 2) {
            return;
        }else{
            query = s.toString();
            if (asyncSearch.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
                asyncSearch = new SearchAddress();
                asyncSearch.execute(query);
                Log.d("ASYNC", "FINISH GOOD");
                Log.d("ASYNC", query);
            }else{
                Log.d("ASYNC", "CANCEL");
                asyncSearch.cancel(false);
                asyncSearch = new SearchAddress();
                asyncSearch.execute(query);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope with this is enough, getStreetList() is working good, giving good results.
If you need something else just ask.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is going to help you, but I've had problems with TextWatcher and AutoCompleteTextView. You should be using a filter on an adapter and not a TextWatcher.

A good implementation of google places + AutoCompleteTextView by google:

https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android